# ASP.NET MVC: How to keep page without Layout in MVC Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, layout, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have MVC 4 area and one of the view in this area needs not to use Layout page.

I am using `_Viewstart` in main application as well as `area` directory both.

Now, In page level, I have already applied `Layout = null` though Layout is applied. Even, I Layout=null apply in area Viewstart file though it appears.

Please help here. How to keep page without layout in area.